# Filled Circle drawKeypoints

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, geometry

I am new to opencv and I am doing a blob detection on a image and then draw circles around each blob using the command-

```
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

I get the output as:
[image: Output Image of the blob detection]

What I want to know is that how can I get these red circles as filled circles?

Comment: for each circle: use cv2.circle with line-widthparameter -1

Comment: @Micka could you be more specific to my case.. as you see I don't use the cv2.circle to make these circles but i guess it is called internally

Comment: I dont know the python api well. You keypoints should hold a position. Just use cv2.circle in a loop instead of drawKeypoints. If you want to adapt the drawKeypoints function, have a look at the opencv source code and copy it.

Answer (score 2):

You have the **keypoints** and the **image** so try this code.

```
def draw_keypoints(img, keypoints, color=(0, 255, 255)):
    for kp in keypoints:
        x, y = kp.pt
        cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), color=color, radius=10, thickness=-1) # you can change the radius and the thickness
```